# Cordova iOS Application getting crashed when using cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting the following error while using cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin in iOS application and due to memory warning the app is then crashing:

"Communications error:  { count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }"

I have noticed this error, when the done button of audio recording view is clicked. On done button click, i am reading the base64 of the recorded audio file and then converting this to blob data. So, i am not sure exactly if this is due to base64 encoding or due to audio capture.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your cordova version & iOS version? And does it crash on startup or after doing something specific? Try to ask specific question where the problem is as isolated as possible.

Comment: Cordova version is 6.4.0 and iOS version is 4.2.1. I am getting this error randomly.